# What exactly do the three "special locales" called "en_US_POSIX", "en_001" and "en_150" mean?

Tags: windows-10, formatting, locale, posix

There are quite a few English-language locales on my computer system (Windows 10). Most of them look like this, and make sense:

```
en_CA
en_DE
en_GB
en_IL
en_PK
en_US
...
```

But there are three special ones, which don't seem to correspond to a clear physical area:

```
en_001
en_150
en_US_POSIX
```

By doing some digging, I have extracted out the following "display names" for them (in order):

```
World
Europe
United States
```

Okay, so "001" means "World", "150" means "Europe" and "US_POSIX" means "United States", just as "en_US" already does?

What is the point of the duplicate "en_US" locales, and what is "World" and "Europe"?

It should be noted that numbers seem to be formatted just like in the US variants for both "World" and "Europe", which is unexpected. I thought they were gonna be using spaces for thousands delimiters, as I thought was considered the "international" standard, but they use commas, just like in the USA/UK:

```
123,456,789
```

Comment: The exact formats used are specified in [ICU Locale “American English (Computer)” (en\_US\_POSIX)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-US-POSIX/index.html), [ICU Locale “English (World)” (en\_001)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-001/index.html), and [ICU Locale “English (Europe)” (en\_150)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-150/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

001 and 150 are [UN M.49](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/#geo-regions) codes for "the world" and "Europe" respectively.

`en_US_POSIX` was invented to refer to the `C` (or 'null') locale code [used in POSIX libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).  It's basically American English, with some peculiarities.

Note that this last one is under [heavy discussion](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-14487) at this instant.

Comment: Isn't C locale the root locale in ICU instead? As C locale in computers means "no localisation" rather than any form of American English, which should mean root locale.

If a developer isn't free to use any "base" language he's comfortable in when producing software, but forced to use American English, this is American exceptionalism.

Comment: Nope!  C does not mean "no localisation" (or localization with a different localisation). The root is called "root" or sometimes "und"

Answer (score 3):

Those particular numbers indicate a region rather than a country, though there are numeric codes for countries as well.

`en-001` is basically international English, or more accurately, international US English, as it uses US spellings. However, its date formats all use the less confusing day month year order. The decimal number and currency separator is `.`, and the grouping separator is `,`.

It was created to break from using `en-US` as if it was standard English, especially given the screwed up date formatting which confuses most anybody else.

`en-150` is the same as `en-001` except that the decimal and grouping separators are swapped as per European practice.

Hopefully, browser spelling tools will begin to accept either spellings for words (like `colour` and `color`, `colorise` and `colorize`, `metre` and `meter`), rather than just assume everybody internationally uses US spelling, especially as there are already 100+ locales that use English. As it is, UK|AU|NZ|??) spellings have to be added to their dictionaries -- tedious!

Other regional locales are `ar-001` for world Arabic, and `es-419` for Latin American Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You may find all this information in the webpage
[ICU Locale “English” (en)](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en/index.html).

You would fine there that
[en_US_POSIX](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-US-POSIX/index.html)
is called "American English" and implies all sort of specific American settings
as regarding dates, numbers, currency and much more.

[en_001](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-001/index.html)
has only some slight changes from en_US_POSIX.

As regarding the use of commas, just remember that this was decided by American
developers from an American company named Microsoft.